# How to remove a Google URL suggestion which doesn't have the delete option?

Tags: google-chrome, address-bar

I’ve got a URL in my Chrome memory that auto-populates whenever I type `www.theage.com.au` into the URL bar. It’s an article I looked at 5 years ago – it’s very specific so definitely not a Google suggestion.
I’ve cleared my history so it is not there.  When I type `www.theage.com.au` then wait, I see it included in the list of URLs that I can select from, but when I hover over it, I don’t see the x on the right, so I can't delete it.

Then if I click into the full link to see the article, then type in `www.theage.com.au` I see two listings with this link, one that I can delete (just created) and one that I can't.

I've included an image of this. In the image you can see two suggestions, one (highlighted) with the x to delete, and the other one without the x, which I can't delete.

I tested this out by typing ‘google’ and ‘why’ in the URL bar and in each case saw a few things that I had entered, which I can delete and a few suggestions (nothing I've asked, but obviously a Google suggestion, which of course I can't delete).

How can I remove this suggestion?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it possible that the entry you cannot delete is a bookmark?

Try searching your bookmarks manager (Menu -> Bookmarks -> Bookmarks Manager) for the webpage and delete the bookmark.

Comment: Good thinking - yes it is.  It's the sort of article that I'd never imagine I would bookmark (about a sportsplayer I don't really care much about) but yes, it is.  Thanks!